# Dividing Counts only of certain groups

Tags: r

An example of data

```
Var1 <- rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"),2)
Var2 <- rep(c("A","B"),3)
Count<-sample(c(10:100), 6)
data<-data.frame(Var1,Var2,Count)
```

Produces

```
   Var1 Var2 Count
1    X    A    89
2    Y    B    97
3    Z    A    29
4    X    B    38
5    Y    A    50
6    Z    B    88
```

I would like to divide the counts **only** of Var2 B by two, to get

```
   Var1 Var2 Count Count2
1    X    A    89    89
2    Y    B    97    48.5
3    Z    A    29    29
4    X    B    38    19
5    Y    A    50    50
6    Z    B    88    44
```

But I'm not sure how to only divide based on a variable.

I'm new to coding, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: In base R: `df$Count2 = ifelse(df$Var2 == "B", df$Count/ 2, df$Count)`

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something like ifelse, but couldn't work it out!

Comment: `within(mydf, { Count2 <- Count; Count2[Var2 == "B"] <- Count2[Var2 == "B"]/2 })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight variation to Brian's dplyr solution, use `replace` to update a portion of the column inside the `mutate` function.

```
require(tidyverse)

Var1 <- rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"),2)
Var2 <- rep(c("A","B"),3)
Count<-sample(c(10:100), 6)
data<-data.frame(Var1,Var2,Count)

data %<>%
  mutate(Count=replace(Count, Var2=='B', Count[Var2=='B']/2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
data$Count2 <- data$Count  ## copy to new variable
## Then change the subset to desired value. LHS subsets, RHS provides change
data$Count2[data$Var2 == "B"] <- data$Count[data$Var2 == "B"]/2
```

And Tidyverse/dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
data = data %>%
      mutate(Count2 = ifelse(Var2 == "B", Count/2, Count ))

# alternatively, this is identical to above
data = mutate(data, Count2 = ifelse(Var2 == "B", Count/2, Count ))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, Count := as.numeric(Count)][Var2 == 'B', Count := Count/2]
```